# Gmail add-on: Save email as .eml to a local directory

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

Attempting to build a simple functionality that when executed saves the opened email as `.eml` to the local computer.

With the below code the email is saved as `original_msg.txt`

In Chrome settings you can force a "Save As" dialog to open and default it to `.eml`, which is fine, but the problem is when you execute the script it opens a blank tab which remains open even after your download is finished.

I'm looking at either closing the tab somehow, or changing the way I'm approaching this task.

Code.gs

```
function saveEmail(e) {
  // Activate temporary Gmail add-on scopes, in this case so that the
  // open message metadata can be read.
  var accessToken = e.messageMetadata.accessToken;
  GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(accessToken);

  // Build URL to open based on a base URL and the message ID.
  var messageId = e.messageMetadata.messageId;
  var url = "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0?view=att&th=" + messageId + "&attid=0&disp=comp&safe=1&zw";
  return CardService.newUniversalActionResponseBuilder()
      .setOpenLink(CardService.newOpenLink()
          .setUrl(url))
      .build();
}
```

appscript.json

```
{
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.metadata"
  ],
  "gmail": {
    "name": "Save Email",
    "logoUrl": "https://www.example.com/hosted/images/2x/my-icon.png",
    "universalActions": [{
        "text": "Save Email",
        "runFunction": "saveEmail"
      }],
    "version": "TRUSTED_TESTER_V2"
  }
}
```